# cygwin curl, Wget, wget and top "command not found"

Tags: windows, unix, command, cygwin

I am pretty sure I have already installed the cygwin default package including the "net" package, however the console kept saying that "command not found" every time I tried to run `wget` and `top.` Do these commands come separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you add the environment variables ?

more info here : http://thehacklist.blogspot.com/2009/04/cygwin-ls-command-not-found.html

Comment: sometime u need to restart the pc ... give it a shot

Answer (score 7):

okay folks, thanks for your time, I have solved it; It seems that the default package that contains wget and curl was not really installed..which confused me since I am pretty sure I had them installed properly. well, the most important thing is that it is solved, so there's no problem now. Thanks again!

[how to install pacakge](https://www.google.jo/search?q=cygwin%20install%20curl%20package&oq=cygwin%20install%20curl%20package&aqs=chrome..69i57.8899j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: run your setup.exe installer again and when it asks you what packages to install search for wget or whatever and then click on the icon that says "skip" to change it into an "install"

Comment: for me, the package needed was 'web'